# Building relationships in Neo4j via Py2neo is very slow

Tags: pandas, neo4j, py2neo

We have 5 different types of nodes in database. Largest one has ~290k, the smallest is only ~3k. Each node type has an id field and they are all indexed. I am using `py2neo` to build relationship, but it is very slow (~ 2 relationships inserted per second)

I used `pandas` read from a relationship csv, iterate each row to create a relationship wrapped in transaction. I tried batch out 10k creation statements in one transaction, but it does not seem to improve the speed a lot.

**Below is the code:**

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\relationship.csv",dtype = datatype, skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields)
df.fillna('',inplace=True)

def f(node_1 ,rel_type, node_2):
    try:
        tx = graph.begin()
        tx.evaluate('MATCH (a {node_id:$label1}),(b {node_id:$label2}) MERGE (a)-[r:'+rel_type+']->(b)',
                    parameters = {'label1': node_1, 'label2': node_2})
        tx.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if(index%1000000 == 0):
        print(index)
    try:
        f(row["node_1"],row["rel_type"],row["node_2"])
    except:
        print("error index: " + index)
```

Can someone help me what I did wrong here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state that there are "5 different types of nodes" (which I interpret to mean 5 node *labels*, in neo4j terminology). And, furthermore, you state that their `id` properties are already indexed.

But your `f()` function is not generating a Cypher query that uses the labels at all, and neither does it use the `id` property. In order to take advantage of your indexes, your Cypher query has to specify the node label and the `id` value.

Since there is currently no efficient way to parameterize the label when performing a `MATCH`, the following version of the `f()` function generates a Cypher query that has hardcoded labels (as well as a hardcoded relationship type):

```
def f(label_1, id_1, rel_type, label_2, id_2):
    try:
        tx = graph.begin()
        tx.evaluate(
                'MATCH' +
                '(a:' + label_1 + '{id:$id1}),' +
                '(b:' + label_2 + '{id:$id2}) ' +
                'MERGE (a)-[r:'+rel_type+']->(b)',
            parameters = {'id1': id_1, 'id2': id_2})
        tx.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

The code that calls `f()` will also have to be changed to pass in both the label names and the `id` values for `a` and `b`. Hopefully, your `df` rows will contain that data (or enough info for you to derive that data).

Comment: Every node labels has node_id property which is indexed, so if i dont specify label in match, it wont be able to use the index at all? The relationship csv only contains starting node id, relationship, ending node id. I could figure out the starting node label and ending node label by checking the relationship but there are just so many relationships and the code will get ugly by doing that.

Comment: Indexing can only be used for matching a node if your query specifies the node label and the indexed property value. So, it looks like you will have to add code to check the relationship (if you cannot change the CSV file contents).

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is for better performance then you will need to consider a different pattern for loading these, i.e. batching. You're currently running one Cypher MERGE statement for each relationship and wrapping that in its own transaction in a separate function call.

Batching these by looking at multiple statements per transaction or per function call will reduce the number of network hops and should improve performance.

Comment: I tried batch 10k merge statements in one transaction, but it does not seem to improve the performance in any significance.